# Convert an image to Unicode (emoji)?

Tags: script, json

I need some help, how can I create a unicode (emoji) from an image, an image being specifically a PNG or SVG image ?

Comment: I am not sure that you can, - if I am not mistaken your image would first have to be accepted, recognised, and ratified by W3.org. Take a look at the following, though (it may give you an alternative selection): https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

Comment: @YTreehuggerCymru Creating a custom Emoji and simply having it stored on my computer cannot be accomplished; I thought Emojis were open and universal, seems they are a closed format.

Comment: I think that you are probably failing to understand what you are dealing with in this, so rather than trying to re-invent the wheel it would probably be better to point you to the following: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_15924

Comment: The above links explain things much more clearly than I can, and should allow you see why you cannot just create your own unicode emoji.

Comment: I found a solution to my problem, for what I'm trying to do I can use base64 for custom emojis.

Comment: I am glad that you have found a solution and apologise for not being able to help you more. Thanks, too, for sharing your solution.